# mat-checkbox: The checkboxes are checked by default and affect each other?

Tags: angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have 7 checkboxes in my `RactiveForm`. This is how I am generating them using `FormArray`:

ts:

```
  weekDaysDe: string[] = ['Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'So'];

  taskForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    weekDays: this.formBuilder.array([
      this.formBuilder.control(false),
      this.formBuilder.control(false),
      this.formBuilder.control(false),
      this.formBuilder.control(false),
      this.formBuilder.control(false),
      this.formBuilder.control(false),
      this.formBuilder.control(false),
    ]),
  });
```

html:

```
      <!-- weekdays -->
      <div class="task-form-control" *ngIf="isRecurrent">
        <mat-label>Tage</mat-label>
        <div class="weekdays" formArrayName="weekDays">
          <mat-checkbox
            *ngFor="
              let weekDay of taskForm.get('weekDays').value;
              let i = index
            "
            color="primary"
            labelPosition="before"
            [formControlName]="i"
            >{{ weekDaysDe[i] }}</mat-checkbox
          >
        </div>
      </div>
```

The checkboxes are rendered as expected but there are two problems:

1. They are all checked at first
2. They check/uncheck each other. For example when I check the first one the last one also get checked

[image]

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In template, Use Form Array controls to iterate over with *ngFor.

**Try this:**

```
 <div class="weekdays" formArrayName="weekDays">
            <mat-checkbox *ngFor="
              let weekDay of weekDaysArray.controls;
              let i = index
            " color="primary" labelPosition="before" [formControlName]="i">{{ weekDaysDe[i] }}
            </mat-checkbox>
   </div>
```

Access the FormArray control with a getter method like this.

**componen.ts**

```
 get weekDaysArray() : FormArray{
    return this.taskForm.get('weekDays') as FormArray;
  }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6zhwtz)

Comment: thanks for the example. that works fine. but I could not use the "controls" property. it said that property does not exist on type formarray.

Comment: Can you try using getter metod?

Comment: thanks. that worked.  I needed to cast the FormArray type in order to user the .controls property

Comment: Hi @Chellappanவ can you please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65244092/angular-checkbox-unique-selection?noredirect=1#comment115346008_65244092

Comment: i was trying to get results for a single checkbox. i just added formControlName and it worked perfectly in update condition too