# Angular - Checkbox unique selection

Tags: html, angular, checkbox

In my project I have created `Select/ Unselect Checkbox functionality`. There are multiple `different checkbox` on same page. How can I separate `Select All` Checkbox functionality so that its only applied to its values.

`Demo code`
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-all-bx4qen?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Note - There are atleast 8 such separate Checkbox in my project. I am looking for optimal solution

Comment: Add one more variable for second checkbox similar to selected and toggle the value based on click event

Comment: Do you mean I should use different variable name for 2nd checkbox like `<mat-checkbox (ngModelChange)="selected1 = !selected1" [ngModel]="checked">Check/ Uncheck</mat-checkbox>`?

Comment: yes, use different variable for each group of checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

you need to have different variable for each check box group. but since you have mentioned that , there are many checkboxes.

here is the optimized solution.

Introduce an array for representation, that way you need to change anything on html if you introduce new checkbox and you can separate ngModel even for sub checkboxes as well.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  selected: boolean = false;
  checkboxes: any = [
    {
      label: "First",
      root: false,
      create: false,
      update: false,
      delete: false
    },
    {
      label: "Second",
      root: false,
      create: false,
      update: false,
      delete: false
    },
    { label: "Third", root: false, create: false, update: false, delete: false }
  ];

  handeClick(checkbox): void {
    checkbox.root = !checkbox.root;
    checkbox.create = checkbox.root;
    checkbox.update = checkbox.root;
    checkbox.delete = checkbox.root;
  }
}
```

```html
|<div *ngFor="let checkbox of checkboxes">
    <h2>{{checkbox.label}}</h2>
    <mat-checkbox (ngModelChange)="handeClick(checkbox)" [ngModel]="checkbox.root">Check/ Uncheck</mat-checkbox>

    <mat-checkbox [ngModel]="checkbox.create">Create</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox [ngModel]="checkbox.update">Update</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox [ngModel]="checkbox.delete">Delete</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

here is the demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-all-qoehwy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Hi this is partially working, problem is it is creating multiple copies of same data. Please check here - https://screenrec.com/share/S5MkI2eK8R Thank you

Comment: can you share the code and update it in stackblitz ?